# override wishlist block in custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, override-block

I want to override wishlist block in my custom theme. Whenever Customer increases the QTY on wishlist page for add to cart, I want to place the condition that QTY should be less than 5.

This function is already written in `/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist/Item/Column/Cart.php`.

I want to override this in my custom theme.

app/code/local/Gt/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist/Item/Column/Cart.php

```
class Gt_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column_Cart extends 

Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column
{
    /**
     * Returns qty to show visually to user
     *
     * @param Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item $item
     * @return float
     */
    public function getAddToCartQty(Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item $item)
    {
        $qty = $item->getQty();
        return $qty ? $qty : 1;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve column related javascript code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJs()
    {
        $js = "
            function addWItemToCart(itemId) {
                var url = '" . $this->getItemAddToCartUrl('%item%') . "';
                url = url.gsub('%item%', itemId);
                var form = $('wishlist-view-form');
                if (form) {
                    var input = form['qty[' + itemId + ']'];
                    if (input) {
                        var separator = (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) ? '&' : '?';
                        url += separator + input.name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input.value);
                        if(input.value > 5){
                            alert('Select between 1 to 5');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                setLocation(url);
            }
        ";

        $js .= parent::getJs();
        return $js;
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Gt/Wishlist/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.6.0.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Gt_Wishlist>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Gt_Wishlist>
  </modules>
    <resources>
        <Gt_Wishlist_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Gt_Wishlist</module>
            </setup>
        </Gt_Wishlist_setup>
    </resources>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <wishlist>
        <rewrite>
          <column_cart>Gt_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column_Cart</column_cart>
        </rewrite>
    </wishlist>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

These two files i have overriden in my custom theme as i shared folder path. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite `Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist/Item/Column/Cart.php` in **local codepool** instead of **theme**.

`app/code/...` will be rewrited in **local codePool**.

`app/design/...` will be overrited in **current theme**.

Now according to this rules, your block will be rewrited of course in `local`.

You have good [This Inchoo explanation](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) for rewriting blocks, helpers, controllers, etc...

Comment: I have read that blog, but I am not getting properly. I i want to only override that cart.php, is it compulsory to override other folders such etc, controllers, models, sql ??
Please help me.

Comment: No, you have just rewrite this block, and not necessarily the others controllers, models ...

Comment: so what will be the next step to override this cart.php. I have done this 3 times. but not overriding that block.